# generate public link for Google Cloud Storage objects

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

How to generate public link for Google Cloud Storage objects that were submitted by users through BlobStore API?

Comment: Do you know the bucket name and the object name, and should the data be publicly accessible or just accessible once by one particular end user?

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough I was looking for a permanent link and publicly accessible. However, I read about the "signed links" and it worked well for me as shown in my answer below. But, does it have limitations? Like max expiry timestamp? Or should I only generate signed link whenever a user requests it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to serve public GCS objects. One is signed URLs. Another is the `getServingUrl()` App Engine method.

However, if the object should be visible to everyone, you can do something simpler. Set the object's permissions to grant READ permission to "AllUsers", which allows the object to be read without any authentication, then simply refer users to this path:

https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET_NAME/OBJECT_NAME

That's it!

You can set an object to be publicly readable from the cloud console, via the APIs, or with this gsutil command: `gsutil acl ch -g AllUsers:R gs://BUCKET_NAME/OBJECT_NAME`

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer. Regarding `getServingUrl()`, it is a method of `ImagesService` interface, so I assume that it is applicable for images only. I think I will go with granting READ permission to all users. However, I need to automate the permission granting, how to do that via API?

Comment: You can grant read permissions in a few ways. I'm not sure how you're creating these objects, but most methods allow you to specify the ACL for the object as you upload it. You can also specify the default ACL that will be applied for uploaded objects in a bucket. You could also use the GCS API to set the ACL on an object.

Comment: I was trying to generate the same for local dev environment, and I've found out that it can be done in that way: `http://localhost:8080/_ah/gcs/<bucket>/<object>`

Comment: Now that Firebase is integraged with Google Cloud, how can we set a Firebase Dynamic Link to a Firebase Storage Object? Please see my question http://stackoverflow.com/q/37360664/4419474

Answer (score 0):

How to generate public link for Google Cloud Storage objects?

1. Create a service account manually via the [console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) and generate a `.p12` key file.
2. After the user uploads the file to the URL that was generated using:

```
blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/fileUploadingHandler", 
        UploadOptions.Builder.withMaxUploadSizeBytes(1024*1024*10) // 10 MB max
                             .googleStorageBucketName(BUCKET_NAME));
```

the servlet (that handles `/fileUploadingHandler`) can retrieve the file name of the GCS object and generate a temporary signed public link as follows:

```
Map<String, List<FileInfo>> fileInfoMap = blobstoreService.getFileInfos(request);
List<FileInfo> fileInfos = fileInfoMap.get("fileName");
FileInfo fileInfo = fileInfos.get(0);
String[] parts = fileInfo.getGsObjectName().split("/"); // get rid of /gs/buck_name/
String fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];
String signedUrl = GcsUrlSigner.generateSignedUrl(fileName);
// send the temporary public link (signedUrl) back to the user
```

```
import com.google.api.client.util.Base64;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Signature;

/**
 * Created by Fouad on 22-Dec-15.
 */
public class GcsUrlSigner
{
    private static final String DEFAULT_BUCKET_NAME = "XXXXXXXX.appspot.com";
    private static final String PUBLIC_URL_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "XXXXXXXX@XXXXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
    private static final String PUBLIC_URL_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = "XXXXXX.p12"; // located in the same folder as GcsUrlSigner.java
    private static final String PUBLIC_URL_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PASSWORD = "notasecret";
    private static final long PUBLIC_URL_EXPIRATION_SECONDS = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 + 60; // 60 seconds

    public static String generateSignedUrl(String objectName) throws Exception
    {
        return generateSignedUrl(DEFAULT_BUCKET_NAME, objectName);
    }

    public static String generateSignedUrl(String bucketName, String objectName) throws Exception
    {
        PrivateKey key = loadKeyFromPkcs12(PUBLIC_URL_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, PUBLIC_URL_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
        return getSigningURL(key, "GET", PUBLIC_URL_EXPIRATION_SECONDS, bucketName, objectName);
    }

    private static String getSigningURL(PrivateKey key, String verb, long expirationSeconds, String bucketName, String objectName) throws Exception
    {
        String url_signature = signString(key, verb + "\n\n\n" + expirationSeconds + "\n" + "/" + bucketName + "/" + objectName);
        String signed_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/" + bucketName + "/" + objectName +
                "?GoogleAccessId=" + PUBLIC_URL_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL +
                "&Expires=" + expirationMillis +
                "&Signature=" + URLEncoder.encode(url_signature, "UTF-8");
        return signed_url;
    }

    private static PrivateKey loadKeyFromPkcs12(String filename, char[] password) throws Exception
    {
        InputStream is = GcsUrlSigner.class.getResourceAsStream(PUBLIC_URL_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH);
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        ks.load(is, password);
        return (PrivateKey) ks.getKey("privatekey", password);
    }

    private static String signString(PrivateKey key, String stringToSign) throws Exception
    {
        if(key == null) throw new Exception("Private Key not initalized");

        Signature signer = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        signer.initSign(key);
        signer.update(stringToSign.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        byte[] rawSignature = signer.sign();

        return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(rawSignature), "UTF-8");
    }
}
```