# How to programatically generate a Dynamic Link to a Storage Object in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, deep-linking, firebase-storage

The new version of Firebase introduced in Google IO 2016 has introduced Firebase Dynamic Links (as an extension of the deep linking concept) as well as Firebase Storage (powered by Google Cloud Storage).

How can programatically generate a Firebase Dynamic Link to a Firebase Storage Object?

**EDIT-1**

I understand that we can get the Google Cloud Storage bucket that holds a Storage object and the  full path to the object in the Storage bucket using the following code

```
public String getDynamicLink(StorageReference storageReference)
{
    String dynamicLink = "";

    String bucket = storageReference.getBucket();
    String path = storageReference.getPath();

    // How to generate dynamic link using the bucket and path?
    return dynamicLink;
}
```

**Edit-2**

As per https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/collaboration#browser, you can construct a URL to a Google Cloud Storage object using the following syntax:

```
https://storage.cloud.google.com/<bucket>/<object>
```

How to programatically generate dynamic link using this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Finally got it**

Use the bucket name and storage object path to generate the google cloud storage object url as mentioned in the edits in the question.

Then create a Dynamic Link programmatically by constructing a URL with the following form:

```
https://domain/?link=your_deep_link&apn=package_name[&amv=minimum_version][&ad=1][&al=android_link][&afl=fallback_link]
```

Please see 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android#create-a-dynamic-link-programmatically for further details.

Comment: Yes of course, since the dynamic link would be generated programmatically, it won't show up in the console.

Comment: Seems we can't check the click number

Comment: can you do this with the web version of frebase? I need to do this with my website but I'm not sure how to do it other than saving a link to the download as i am uploading inside my database..

Comment: Though the Firebase dynamic links are designed specifically for android, where system will automatically redirect you to the fallback link when the app isn't installed, you can mirror the behavior using client side scripting for other OS.

Comment: Or in case no client side intelligent action is required, you can use server side scripting to custom process the dynamic links.